# Pushing file to dropbox using dropbox apis through django

Tags: django, oauth, dropbox-api

i am using oauth2 package for django to use dropbox as for pushing file: 
for retrieving account info this signature method works:

```
parameters = {
        'oauth_consumer_key'    : DropboxConstants.app_key,
        'oauth_token'           : dropbox.oauth_token,
        'oauth_signature_method': oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1.name,
        'oauth_timestamp'       : oauth.generate_timestamp(),
        'oauth_nonce'           : oauth.generate_nonce(),
        'oauth_version'         : DropboxConstants.api_version,
        'oauth_signature'       : ''
}


access_token_g = oauth.Token(key=dropbox.oauth_token,secret=dropbox.oauth_token_secret)
#prepare signature
oauth_request       = oauth.Request(method="GET",url=DropboxConstants.account_info_url,parameters=parameters)
signature_method_m  = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

oauth_request.sign_request(signature_method=signature_method_m,
                           consumer=DropboxConstants.consumer,
                           token=access_token_g)

resp, content = DropboxConstants.client.request(oauth_request.to_url())
if resp['status'] != '200':
    print content
    raise Exception("Invalid response from Dropbox.")

account_info = simplejson.loads(content)
```

But for pushing file on dropbox i am using:

```
    parameters = {
        'oauth_consumer_key'    : DropboxConstants.app_key,
        'oauth_token'           : dropbox.oauth_token,
        'oauth_signature_method': oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1.name,
        'oauth_timestamp'       : oauth.generate_timestamp(),
        'oauth_nonce'           : oauth.generate_nonce(),
        'oauth_version'         : DropboxConstants.api_version,
        'oauth_signature'       : '',
        'file'                  : request.FILES['file'].name,
    }

    access_token_g = oauth.Token(key=dropbox.oauth_token,secret=dropbox.oauth_token_secret)

    #prepare signature
    oauth_request       = oauth.Request(method="POST",
                                        url=DropboxConstants.file_access_url,
                                        parameters=parameters)

    signature_method_m  = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

    oauth_request.sign_request(signature_method=signature_method_m,
                               consumer=DropboxConstants.consumer,
                               token=access_token_g)

    resp, content = DropboxConstants.client.request(oauth_request.to_url())
    if resp['status'] != '200':
        print content
        raise Exception("Invalid response from Dropbox.")
```

it gives me this error

```
{"error": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi-content.dropbox.com%2F0%2Ffiles%2Fdropbox%2F&oauth_body_hash%3D2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%252FvlWAYkK%252FYBwk%253D%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dedw6k7d78hu8q8v%26oauth_nonce%3D69188147%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1314863397%26oauth_token%3Dv0b6uxv18z2wrmg%26oauth_version%3D1.0"}

signature that is generated is:
AUHJv%2F%2BCeRP27PsJ1X5eMaSghGU%3D
```

I have come across a post: https://github.com/ourbricks/ourbricks-api-examples/blob/master/python/upload2ourbricks.py#L126-173 but didnt get what has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking, why don't you simply install Dropbox client on the server and push the files to its sync folder?

Comment: i am going to link my app with various Oauth providers...so wanted to abstract the common code into a single Django app...that's why i am using oauth2 app for django rather than using individual clients which will become kinda confusing in maintenance. Do I make sense or you feel i should go other way ??